# Hamcrest - any item in arrayOne matches any item in arrayTwo

Tags: java, filter, hamcrest, lambdaj

I am using LambdaJ and hamcrest in Java. I am wondering if there is a way to check if any item in one array is equal to any item of another array?

I have tried some configurations but I can not seem to get it right.

like this one:

```
arrayOne, hasItemInArray(isIn(arrayTwo));
```

... Does not work because it will try to match every item in arrayOne.

Comment: Is it at the same index? If yes, just test that the lists are `.equals()`

Comment: Thanks, but not really what I was looking for. This matching should assert that arrayOne contains at least one item equal to an item in arrayTwo regardless of index.

Comment: Then just do `boolean found = false; for (final X item: arrayOne) if (arrayTwo.contains(item)) found = true; assertTrue(found);`. LambdaJ and all this are fine, but good "old fashioned" loops always work ;)

Comment: Yes, that would work. However I realise I forgot to mention that this matcher is just one in a series of optional matchers in a multi-filter. These matchers will be combined using `.and()` to filter through a List. So good old loops will not work. Are there no explicit matchers for this? Seems like an easy enough task for Hamcrest and LambdaJ

Comment: Well, you can create your own matcher if you use fest-assert. I don't know much about Hamcrest, but I guess you can create your own matchers as well

Comment: Yes, that would be an option. I think I solved it though, will accept as soon as I'm allowed. Thank you for the support :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I solved it!

The problem was not that Hamcrest does not match the way I described in the question. It was that I had a List of Long:s.

I was refering to `hasItemInArray` which uses `hasValue` (comparing primitive types) rather than `hasItem` (comparing objects).

So the code above works with a minor modification:

```
arrayOne, hasItem(isIn(arrayTwo));
```

This is acually a somewhat confusing naming convention.